# Regex: If brackets, then set to empty, otherwise pass through

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string that may or may not have brackets in it. If there are brackets in the string, then I want to set it to an empty string (or a null value). Otherwise, I want to do `*.?`.

This is what I have so far, but it's definitely not right:
`(?(?=[\[^\]])("")|(.*?))`.

One example string is: `abcdef[12345]`.
I don't want to match on something like: `mousecat`.

What would be the best way to do this operation? There is a Grok template with regex statements that gets executed within a Java program.

Thanks!
Keren

Edit: How to do this if I have numbers within the brackets? Rather than just anything within the brackets.

Comment: You want to set the whole string to an empty string, or just replace the contents of the brackets?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of strings you want to match/not match?

Comment: What's the purpose of `("")` in the regexp?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I think that you are trying to put both the search and replacement pattern into 1 regex. That is not how regex replacement works. You should find a string with a pattern (match it), and then replace. To use multiple replacements, use `preg_replace_callback` if it is PHP, a replacement method allowing an anonymous method where you could pass the match object and decide what to replace the match with.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern:

```
^.*[\[\]].*$|^([^\[\]]*)$
```

The replacement:

```
$1
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! You were faster than me ;)

Comment: You're matching parentheses, not square brackets like in the example.

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood then. Corrected.

Comment: How does it know to make the replacement to $1?

Comment: Because it's in parenthesis (). $1 is first capturing group (surrounded by parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = "abcdef[xxxx]";
console.log(/\[.+\]/i.exec(str))
```